# Assembly.Load throws FileNotFoundException when multiple instances run simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Windows console application that loads an assembly like this:

```
return Assembly.Load(my_assembly_name);
```

I run about 10 instances of this application simultaneously through scripting. Meaning that `my_assembly_name` is being loaded by 10 different applications at the same time.

Occasionally I get this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'my_assembly_name' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find
>   the file specified.

I'm not quite sure of the behind-the-scenes of the `Assembly.Load` method. My question is - could it be that I'm exceeding some sort of limit or that the assembly is being blocked by the other instances of the Windows console application?

Comment: Is the file located at `my_assembly_name` being dynamically generated? Can you explain a bit why you are performing a `Assembly.Load` instead of just a normal reference, the reasoning behind it may explain what is going wrong.

Comment: Thank you @ScottChamberlain. This is an open-source tool for database migrations that supports multiple DBMS, so it loads the proper assembly based on the parameters we pass to it (so if DatabaseType is "sqlserver", it will load that specific assembly).

Comment: "my_assembly_name" is an assembly belongs to the same solution of this database migration tool. It is pre-compiled so it's not dynamically generated. Thank you!